# Find best type fit for a string in Python

Tags: python, types, casting

I have a string variable and I want to find which built-in type describes the value of this variable best. E.g.: `"3.14"` -> float; `"2015-10-23"` -> date; else -> string

Right now I'm simply cascading try and excepts, which is kind of ugly:

```
try:
    float(value)
    return "This is a float"
except ValueError:
    try:
        dateutil.parser.parse(value)
        return "Date"
    except ValueError:
        pass
return "This is a string"
```

Any idea for a "pythonic" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over the parsing attempts:

```
def what_is(value):
    for attempt, type_ in ((float, "This is a float"), 
                           (dateutil.parser.parse, "Date")):
        try:
            _ = attempt(value)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        return type_
    return "This is a string"
```

This is easily scalable to more parsers and will always fall back to the string at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Two follow up questions:
1. Why is it better to place the return at the bottom of the try-except clause? Readability?
2. Is there anything wrong with not-assigning the return value of the parsing function?

Comment: @MatthiasBrandt 1. The `try` block should be as short as possible, and this way is one fewer lines than putting the `return` line in an `else`. 2. No, that would still work, but I think it's better to be explicit that *"this will return something but we're not interested in it"*, which `_ = ` achieves.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a `list` of casting/parsing functions, and try them out one by one:

```
>>> value = '1.2'
>>> answer = None
>>> casts = [int, float, dateutil.parser.parse]
>>> for c in casts:
...     try:
...         answer = c(value)
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
...     else:
...         break
...
>>> answer
1.2
```

Add whatever exception types are relevant for the types you're checking.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was different. Assuming that I want to find the most appropriate type and that I can let python to decide what is the order, I can simply use `eval`:

```
value = '1.2'
try:
    result = eval(value)
except ValueError:
    result = value
type(result)
```